# Render a partial via page.replace_html and using a layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, modal-dialog, render

here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    page.replace_html('manage_categories_list', :partial => "/categories/categories", :layout => :modal)
```

But, I get this error on the above code:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `include?' for :modal:Symbol):
```

What I want to be able to do, is have template HTML for a modal dialog window. And set the header (h2) and the body (div) of that modal with any partial. =\

modal.html.erb:

```
<div class="fixed_modal">
    <div class="modal_header">
        <%= yield :header %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_body">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The partial I'm trying to render:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
    Manage Categories
<% end %>
```

.... rest doesn't matter as it just goes into the yield

I'm using rail 2.3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you need to change it to `..., :layout => 'modal'`:

```
page.replace_html('manage_categories_list', :partial => "/categories/categories", :layout => :modal)
```

The #replace_html method accepts options like #render. For the :layout option, you either need to pass `true`, or a string layout file name (See [the docs for #render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)).

The layout argument will be the 'xyz' part of the filename in app/views/layouts/xyz.html.erb.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to :layout can't be a symbol  try

```
:layout=>'modal'
```

This assumes you have a layout in app/views/layouts/modal.html.erb